# Problem with easy_localization in flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am trying to use easy_localization in my app and my state management in bloc. Everything working fine till I change the language. It is not changing all texts I need. It is changing half of the texts and stopping. It is only changing after hot reload. I have tried to rebuild bloc and it did not help me.

Comment: nothing yet? I'm trying to figure it out, it's hopeless... I think something is not triggering the layout rebuild but don't quite know how to trigger it for the visible screen...

Comment: If you are adding easy_localization after configuring with bloc, or if your eas_localization is not in the bloc nothing can help you there. I have done many things but could not find any solution to it, except managing bloc with easy_localization. Or check this post if you just started your project https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-localization-with-bloc-95672e625580